# How to transpose each element of a Numpy Matrix

Tags: numpy, transpose

I have this Numpy Matrix and I'd like to convert/transpose each row vector element into a column vector element.

This is what I have:

```
[[ -2.12   3.12  1.00]
 [  0.00   0.00  1.00]
 [  7.07   8.07  1.00]
 [ -1.41   2.82  1.00]
 [ -7.07   3.53  1.00]]
```

This is what I want:

```
[[[-2.12][3.12][1.00]]
[[0.00][0.00][1.00]]
[[7.07][8.07][1.00]]
[[-1.41][2.82] [1.00]]
[[-7.07][3.53][1.00]]
```

I've seen some similar question on stack overflow, but none seem to directly apply.  Thanks!

Comment: .. `a[...,None]`?

Comment: The first looks like a (5,3) shape, the second a (5,3,1) shape.